# Applying rowspan in table with ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have array like this

```
$scope.orderno=[
{"orderno":1254,"weight":25875,"group":5},
{"orderno":56787,"weight":25875,"group":5},
{"orderno":567,"weight":25875,"group":3},
{"orderno":123254,"weight":25875,"group":3}
];
```

now i want to show in html like below
[image: expected output]
I tried but i can't.I attached my tried code below.

```
<div ng-app>
  <table ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <thead>
      <div>
        <tr>
          <td>orderno</td>
          <td>weight</td>
          <td rowspan={{orderwt}}>group</td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in orderno">
      <tr>
        <td></td>       
        <td></td>
        <td rowspan="{{orderno.length}}">{{item.group}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{item.orderno}}</td>     
        <td>{{item.weight}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

i tried but i can't find correct answer

Comment: Are those items in the array already ordered and group on the `group` key?

Comment: Your data structure doesn't match at all what you want your view to look like. You need a different data structure. Transform your data so it looks like this : `$scope.orderno={
 "5" : [
  {"orderno":1254,"weight":25875},
  {"orderno":56787,"weight":25875}
 ],
 "3" : [
  {"orderno":567,"weight":25875},
  {"orderno":123254,"weight":25875}
 ]

}` then you'll find it much easier to iterate.

Comment: yes already ordered,but it have dublicates

Comment: @JeremyThille ok.r Tell me how to iterate with your structure

Comment: Hmmm, no :) I already gave you a strong hint with the correct data structure to have, now it's your turn to try and give it a go. It should be much easier with this structure, because it matches your HTML view.

Comment: Ok @JeremyThille

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should do is transform your data into a format that's easier to iterate over. For example, you could use `array.reduce()` to help you create a new object that's keyed by group number. Then you can iterate over this object to create your table.

See example snippet with comments below:

```js
// This is your original data array
let arr = [{
      "orderno": 1254,
      "weight": 25875,
      "group": 5
    },
    {
      "orderno": 56787,
      "weight": 25875,
      "group": 5
    },
    {
      "orderno": 567,
      "weight": 25875,
      "group": 3
    },
    {
      "orderno": 123254,
      "weight": 25875,
      "group": 3
    }
  ],  // Use reduce and Object.create to make a new object keyed by group number
  result = arr.reduce(function(r, a) {
    r[a.group] = r[a.group] || [];
    r[a.group].push(a);
    return r;
  }, Object.create(null));

let app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.groups = result;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <td>Group</td>
      <td>Order No</td>
      <td>Weight</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in groups">  <!-- Outer loop -->
      <tr ng-repeat="group in value"> <!-- Inner loop -->
        <td ng-if="$index == 0" rowspan="{{ value.length }}">{{ group.group }}</td> 
        <!-- the above is so we only add the rowspan once -->
        <td>{{ group.orderno }}</td>
        <td>{{ group.weight }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```